# Extract Row ID from Table - Insert Then Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Is it Possible to extract the ID of the record being inserted in a table at the time of inserting dat particular record into that table  ??? Reference to Sql Server

Comment: Here is the documentation for `insert` (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx).  Read about the `output` clause.

Answer (score 3):

Read about `INSERT` with [`OUTPUT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). This is in my experience the easiest way of achieving an atomic `INSERT` outputting an inserted value.

Example, assuming that `Table` contains an auto-incremented field named `ID`:

```
DECLARE @outputResult TABLE (ID BIGINT)

INSERT INTO Table
(
    Field1,
    Field2
)
OUPUT INSERTED.ID INTO @outputResult
VALUES
(
    ....
)

SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM @outputResult
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the ID afterwards with

```
SELECT @@IDENTITY
```

or

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Comment: They will return the id of the last insertion made by the connection (and scope) your using.